# Passing Kerberos token of the authenticated user from IIS 7 to REST web services

Tags: asp.net, authentication, kerberos

I have a web site running on IIS7 configured to use Windows authentication. I'd like to make a call from the site to a REST web service and pass the Kerberos token of the user (authenticated while accessing the web site) in Authorization header (or any HTTP header). I want REST service to extract additional info like user groups, etc.